# Boolean law on predicate logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have a doubt, in boolean algebra $$p \Rightarrow b \equiv \neg\: b \Rightarrow \neg\: p$$ Can I apply the same rule in predicate logic for example : $$((\forall x| \neg A : \neg E) \Rightarrow (\forall x | \neg A : \neg Q)) \equiv (\neg (\forall x| \neg A : \neg Q) \Rightarrow \neg (\forall x | \neg A : \neg E))$$ or do I need to transform the quantifiers and their expressions.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m unfamiliar with your notation for predicate logic, but yes, a propositional tautology with statements of predicate logic substituted in is a logically valid statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The whole point of propositional logic is to show certain logical relationships hold between sentences without having to know what those sentences are.

As such, when we find that $p \rightarrow b \Leftrightarrow \neg b \rightarrow \neg p$, we know that this is true for *any* sentences $p$ and $b$ ... and this includes sentences from predicate logic.